# How to group foreach statement by id in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreach

I'm having a little challenge, and I am pretty new to mvc. My question is,

How do i group a bunch of foreach statements, by the id of the table it is being called from. here is my code:

```
foreach (
                        var owner in
                            _entities.LLAttrDatas.Where(
                                n => n.AttrID == 2 && n.ValStr.Contains(searchInputModel.OwnersName)))
                    {
                        ViewBag.searchName = owner.ValStr;
                    }

                    foreach (
                        var ownerAddress in
                            _entities.LLAttrDatas.Where(
                                n => n.AttrID == 3 && n.ValStr.Contains(searchInputModel.OwnersAddress)))
                    {
                        ViewBag.searchAddress = ownerAddress.ValStr;
                    }

                    foreach (
                        var propertyAddress in
                            _entities.LLAttrDatas.Where(
                                n => n.AttrID == 4 && n.ValStr.Contains(searchInputModel.DescriptionOrLocationOfProp)))
                    {
                        ViewBag.searchProperty = propertyAddress.ValStr;
                    }

                    foreach (
                        var propertyVolumeNo in
                            _entities.LLAttrDatas.Where(
                                n => n.AttrID == 5 && n.ValStr.Contains(searchInputModel.VolumeNumber)))
                    {
                        ViewBag.searchPropertyVolumeNo = propertyVolumeNo.ValStr;
                    }

                    foreach (
                        var propertyPlanNo in
                            _entities.LLAttrDatas.Where(
                                n => n.AttrID == 6 && n.ValStr.Contains(searchInputModel.SurveyPlanNumber))
                        )
                    {
                        ViewBag.searchPropertyPlanNo = propertyPlanNo.ValStr;
                    }
```

Right now, when a user makes a search against any of the above query, just one result is being shown. I want it to display all the results from the different queries since they all have the same ID. Any help will be highly appreciated thanks.

Thanks y'all for your comments and support. We learn everyday. Anyways, I found a better way of doing it:

```
public IQueryable<DocumentProperty> GetDocuments(DocumentSearchInputModel searchInputModel)
            {
                Context = new DataContext();

                if (Context != null)
                {
                    var result = Context.DocumentsForSearch.AsQueryable();     
                    if (searchInputModel != null)
                    {

                        result =
                            Context.DocumentsForSearch.Where(
                                d =>
                                    d.DescriptionOrLocationOfProp.Contains(searchInputModel.DescriptionOrLocationOfProp)
                                    || d.OwnersAddress.Contains(searchInputModel.OwnersAddress)
                                    || d.OwnersName.Contains(searchInputModel.OwnersName)
                                    || d.SurveyPlanNumber.Contains(searchInputModel.SurveyPlanNumber)
                                    || d.VolumeNumber.Contains(searchInputModel.VolumeNumber)
                                    || d.FileUrl.Contains(searchInputModel.OwnersName));

                    }
                    Logger.Info($"Results found {result}");
                    return result;
                }
                return null;
            }
```

Now the only issue i'm having is how to display the search result in the view. how do i do a foreach where AttrID and ValStr match, and if the user search in only one field (because its a multi search system), I want the result to display all the fields with the same ID (i.e d.ID). Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish... but its wrong. so very wrong. Those foreach loops should be a red flag the size of Mars to you.

Comment: Why are you doing it like that?  Just have one `foreach` loop and some `if`/`else if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do it like this?

```
foreach(var myProp in _entities.LLAttrDatas)
{
    if(myProp.AttrID == 1 && myProp.ValStr.StartsWith("foo"))
        // etc..
    else if (myProp.AttrID == 2 && myProp.ValStr.StartsWith("bar"))
        // etc..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var results = _entities.LLAttrDatas.select(x = > new {
     owner = x.Where(n => n.AttrID == 2 && n.ValStr.Contains(searchInputModel.OwnersName)).FirstOrDefault(),
     ownerAddress = x.Where(n => n.AttrID == 3 && n.ValStr.Contains(searchInputModel.OwnersAddress)).FirstOrDefault(),
     propertyAddress = x.Where(n => n.AttrID == 4 && n.ValStr.Contains(searchInputModel.DescriptionOrLocationOfProp)).FirstOrDefault(),
     propertyVolumeNo = x.Where(n => n.AttrID == 5 && n.ValStr.Contains(searchInputModel.VolumeNumber)).FirstOrDefault(),
     propertyPlanNo = x.Where(n => n.AttrID == 6 && n.ValStr.Contains(searchInputModel.SurveyPlanNumber)).FirstOrDefault()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: This is awfull, really. Don't ever use LINQ like that, this is just unreadable. I will not downvote answer, but it is bad example, not to mention this is GC/CPU killer request.

Comment: I just copied Where statements from original posting.  Wasn't sure how to reduce the where statements and didn't want to post something that wouldn't work.  At least I eliminate the 5 redundant foreach loops.  I suspect the DataSet has 5 DataTables and simply indexing the tables may work.  But not sure.

Comment: his table is just <int,string> key-value storage, probably with some additional meta. AttrID is just alias for search model property. It can be simply rewritten as mapped request.

Answer (score 0):

Your AttrID is obviously alias for properties in your search model. Define the alias table properly and you will improve readability and speed of generated request:

```
        var forwardMap = new Dictionary<int, string>()
                       {
                           {2, searchInputModel.OwnersName},
                           {3, searchInputModel.OwnersAddress},
                           {4, searchInputModel.DescriptionOrLocationOfProp},
                           {5, searchInputModel.VolumeNumber},
                           {6, searchInputModel.SurveyPlanNumber},
                       };

        //common request for all your properties. You can wrap it into function.
        var query = _entities.LLAttrDatas
                             .GroupBy(x => x.AttrID)
                             .Where(x => forwardMap.Keys.Contains(x.Key))
                             .Select(x => new
                                          {
                                              id = x.Key,
                                              val = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ValStr.Contains(forwardMap[x.Key]))
                                          });

        //request to server
        var result = query.ToDictionary(x => x.id, x => x.val);

        //now result contains corresponding values (don't forget to check them for existance, if they are not present in table, they will not be present in result and throw exception)
        ViewBag.searchName = result[2];
        ViewBag.searchAddress = result[3];
        ViewBag.searchProperty = result[4];
        ViewBag.searchPropertyVolumeNo = result[5];
        ViewBag.searchPropertyPlanNo = result[6];
```

Comment: Thanks alot, but I'm having a type argument cannot be inferred from the usage  error at the point of Select.   .Select(x => new
                                          {
                                              id = x.AttrID,
                                              val = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ValStr.Contains(forwardMap[x.AttrId]))
                                          });

Comment: Fixed property names.

Comment: fixed property names? Please I don't understand...